# PAC file proxy setup using Selenium -Browserstack

Tags: java, selenium, proxy, automation, browserstack

I need to set my Browser's proxy with Automatic Proxy configuration URL as shown in the screenshot below.

I am trying to achieve this using Selenium and Browserstack as test environment.

Set the proxy as shown below.

> Proxy proxy = new Proxy();  
>   proxy.setProxyAutoconfigUrl("http://pokgsa.ibm.com/gsa/pokgsa/home/j/m/jmit/web/public/proxy.pac");  
>   DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities(); 
>    caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);  
>              caps.setCapability("browser", "Chrome");  
>               caps.setCapability("browser_version", "63.0");  
>               caps.setCapability("os", "Windows");  
>               caps.setCapability("os_version", "7");  
>               caps.setCapability("resolution", "1366x768");

[image]

Tried to set the proxy configuration locally and it works however it does not work on browserstack. I think the proxy is not getting set on the virtual browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 2);
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.autoconfig_url", "http://pokgsa.ibm.com/gsa/pokgsa/home/j/m/jmit/web/public/proxy.pac");
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
```

You need to pass the pac file details using Firefox profile.

Similarly for chrome, you may refer the following link: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/wiki/Corporate-Proxies#setting-a-proxy-for-running-chrome

Also please ensure proxies in the pac file do not need machine based authentication/entries since this may not work as your proxies would be required to be authenticated on all browserstack IPs

Comment: Thanks. Tried the same however the code is still timing out. I think the proxy is still not getting set. Code pasted below

Comment: < FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();  
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 2);  
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.autoconfig_url", "http://pokgsa.ibm.com/gsa/pokgsa/home/j/m/jmitch/web/public/proxy.pac");     caps.setCapability("browser", "Firefox");  
    caps.setCapability("browser_version", "57.0");  
    caps.setCapability("os", "Windows");  
    caps.setCapability("os_version", "10");  
    caps.setCapability("resolution", "1366x768");

Comment: Use the following code snippet instead. You are not passing the profile to capabilities: FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(); profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 2); profile.setPreference("network.proxy.autoconfig_url", "http://pokgsa.ibm.com/gsa/pokgsa/home/j/m/jmit/web/public/proxy.pac"); caps.setCapability("browser", "Firefox"); caps.setCapability("browser_version", "57.0"); caps.setCapability("os", "Windows"); caps.setCapability("os_version", "10"); caps.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile); WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), caps);